# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apps.news'; 'apps' is not a package

Tags: python, django, import, python-import, modulenotfounderror

I have a Django project with the following structure:

```
project
   apps
      news
      __init__.py
         models.py
   hose
      tasks.py
```

Within tasks.py, I have this import

```
from apps.news.models import Company
```

When I try to run tasks.py, I get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apps.news'; 'apps' is not a package
```

How do I fix this error? I don't understand why this import does not work.

Comment: For the import to work, the project directory needs to be on the Python path. You could acheive that by making `tasks.py` a [management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-management-commands/#module-django.core.management), moving `tasks.py` into the project directory (alongside `manage.py`), or by manually adding the project directory to the Python path e.g. `import sys; sys.path.append('/path/to/project')` or `import sys; sys.path.append('..')`

Comment: I tried this and it still didn't work. Same error

Comment: *I tried this and it still didn't work* - I made three different suggestions, so I've got no idea what you actually tried. If you post `tasks.py` and the full traceback then it might be clearer what the problem is, but at the moment I don't have any other suggestions.

Comment: i have the same problem. Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Reference: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages

You need to add an empty `__init__.py` (4 underscores in total) file in the apps folder for it to be recognized by Python as a package.

Comment: I have that there. I will add to question.

Comment: In your question it's not clear if `__init__.py` is in `apps`, `apps/news` or both.

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody else is still struggling with this. I had the `__init__.py` in the `app` folder but it still didn't work. Running the following command in `app` *parent* folder worked for me.

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PWD
```